# Python library for playing music file list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple music player website(single page) that plays selected musics by a user. A list of file names will be stored in an array and my python code should play them one by one while looping the array. I wonder if there's a good library to help me implement it. I've checked python library that handles wav files... but I don't feel like this is good enough :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what formats you want to support how far you want to go. Given that decoding most audio formats and playing them is CPU intensive, you should probably use some kind of native library that does this part for you. My first thought is [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html). You might also be able to use different libraries for different formats. [Here](http://www.wezm.net/technical/2008/04/mp3-decoder-libraries-compared/) is a a list of mp3 libraries and then use cffi or something else to call routines in them from Python while having Python itself deal only with things like UI and playlist management. Yet another option is to have a subprocess which runs a regular decoder and player like mpg123 or something else and have your python program manage it. That's not as silly as it sounds and I've used [emms](http://www.gnu.org/software/emms/) for a long time to play my mp3s in this fashion and it worked very well.